# When trying to use google api v3 to retrieve my list of youtube videos uploads it's not continue after the request?

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

The program just hang after trying to make a request and never continue.
Tried to use try and ctach but it's not throwing any exceptions or errors.

This is my code in a new class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;


namespace Youtube
{


    class Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads
    {
        public Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads()
        {
            try
            {
                Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\jason file\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for read-only access to the authenticated 
                    // user's account, but not other types of account access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var channelsListRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
            channelsListRequest.Mine = true;

            // Retrieve the contentDetails part of the channel resource for the authenticated user's channel.
            var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
            {
                // From the API response, extract the playlist ID that identifies the list
                // of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var uploadsListId = channel.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

                Console.WriteLine("Videos in list {0}", uploadsListId);

                var nextPageToken = "";
                while (nextPageToken != null)
                {
                    var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                    playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                    // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                    var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

                    foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
                    {
                        // Print information about each video.
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
                    }

                    nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used a break point and when it's doing the line:

```
var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

It's just hanging the program never continue.

Comment: I found how to upload videos list my videos and also to delete videos. I will upload my code later today.

Comment: Per the other question I came here to look.  But I'm guessing you found the solution already based on this comment?

Comment: Yes it's more mix of the two questions. To delete the other one ?

Comment: I say leave it and then also answer this question with your working code when you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

I admit that it's not ideal solution rather one of possible but, in my case, I have removed "await" and  *Async() keywords and it works now.

```
var channelsListResponse = channelsListRequest.Execute();
```

instead of

```
var channelsListResponse = await channelsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

And

```
var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();
```

instead of

```
var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```