# How can i make that when searching for youtube uploads using google api v3 it will show more then 50 results?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If i make the max results to be 400 it will make exception since it should be between 0-50 to 400.
So for now for testing i did it 50.

How can i make somehow that when it found 50 results and added them to the List it will make then another search for the next 50 results and so on until the end ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;


namespace Automatic_Record
{


    class Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads
    {
        public Youtube_Retrieve_Uploads()
        {
            test();
            /*try
            {
                Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }*/
        }

        private void test()
        {
            YouTubeService yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "AIzaSyDcqx8nMWQL9wshpAs0Q-h0twpGd6R1BJM" });
            List<string> videos = new List<string>();

            var searchListRequest = yt.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.ChannelId = "UCUE_2qgW-nJOjOlO28uZHtQ";//"UCbe-iLd-TEl3_YQaNSm8dng";
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            var searchListResult = searchListRequest.Execute();

            foreach (var item in searchListResult.Items)
            {
                if (item.Snippet.Title.StartsWith("Gta"))
                {
                    videos.Add("ID: " + item.Id.VideoId);
                    videos.Add("SNIPPET: " + item.Snippet.Title);
                }
            }  
        }
```

This is working fine but i'm getting only 50 results. I want to get the whole videos starts with Gta but in general i want to get the first 50 results then the next 50 then the next 50 until there are no more results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through pages by using a token to identify which page you're on.

Follow the nextPageToken variable through this example:

```
var nextPageToken = "";
        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
          var playlistItemsListRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
          playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
          playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
          playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

          // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
          var playlistItemsListResponse = await playlistItemsListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

          foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
          {
            // Print information about each video.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", playlistItem.Snippet.Title, playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId);
          }

          nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
        }
```

See this link for more help and examples:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Comment: Don that's what i tried to do but i had a problem with this sample. Can you try looking at my other question about this sample ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053384/when-trying-to-use-google-api-v3-to-retrieve-my-list-of-youtube-videos-uploads-i